# How can I get Show More to show if there are more than 3 items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to make Show More to show if there are more than 3 list items in each container. I am not having any success with this probably because I'm not targeting the container list items correctly. Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="main">Women</a>
<div class="dropDown">
  <div class="taxonomy">
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <span class="show-more">Show More</span>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="main">Men</a>
<div class="dropDown">
  <div class="taxonomy">
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <span class="show-more">Show More</span>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="main">Children</a>
<div class="dropDown">
  <div class="taxonomy">
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <span class="show-more">Show More</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 2em;
}

.dropDown {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

span.show-more {
  display: none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('#dropDown').each(function() {
  if($(this).children().children('li').length > 3) {
    $(this).children('.show-more').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried - show us the code

Comment: Sorry, should be updated with code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to re-implement mine so it automatically generates html for the "More"/"Less" button.

```js
$(".readmore").each(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
      $lis = $this.children(),
      $a = $("<a href='javascript:void(0)'>Less</a>")
  if ($lis.length > 3) {
    $this.after($a);
    $a.click(function () {
      $lis.slice(3).toggle();
      $a.html($a.html() === "More" ? "Less" : "More")
    }).click();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="readmore">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
<ul class="readmore">
  <li>less than three</li>
  <li>still less than three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for that but what I was wondering is how can I have the Show More text to only show if there are more than 3 items. I want to have the Show More text to be displayed none by default unless there are more than 3 items.

Comment: @Hyona Updated.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Hyona  if you could mark as answer / upvote it'd help a lot. You're welcome!

Comment: Hm weird, I thought I upvoted this last night but guess not. Anyhow I clicked on the checkmark as answered clicked on upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the container list array length and show that Show more text based on the array length.

Answer (score 0):

I based my answer of your existing html structure.  However, I think it should be cleaned up and corrected.  A few things of note:

- You're `<li>` elements should be children of either `<ol>` or `<ul>` (not `<div>`).
- I didn't do anything with your `<a>` tag headings because I wasn't sure what you're going for with them.
- Not sure why you're using a `<span>` for a *"show more"* link when you could use an `<a>` for that.

Anyhow, I based my answer by keeping you're structure intact.  what I did was get the length of the `<div>` by filtering only `<li>` elements and displaying show *"show more"* if the length is > 3.  I also hide any elements with an index 3 or greater.  I then created a click handler for your *"show more"* `<span>` tag.

```js
$('.dropDown div').each(function() {
  var list = $(this).children().filter("li");

  $.each(list, function(i, value) {
    if (i > 2) $(this).hide();
  });

  if (list.length > 3) {
    $(this).find(".show-more").show();
  }
});

$(".show-more").click(function () {
  $(this).closest("div").children().filter("li").show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 2em;
}

.dropDown {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

span.show-more {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #00F;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="main">Women</a>
<div class="dropDown">
  <div class="taxonomy">
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <span class="show-more">Show More</span>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="main">Men</a>
<div class="dropDown">
  <div class="taxonomy">
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <span class="show-more">Show More</span>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="main">Children</a>
<div class="dropDown">
  <div class="taxonomy">
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <li>Sweater</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Shorts</li>
    <span class="show-more">Show More</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Yeah this was actually a copy of code that was already implemented by someone else and so this is what I had to work with unfortunately. I appreciate it.